# pegar dados no method post

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou enviando um objeto com angular, mas não estou conseguindo pegar os dados no node express

metodo enviado com angular.

```
this.appService.getcheckout(this.post()).subscribe(checkout => {
      this.log = this.log+ checkout
    });
post(){
    return [
      {
          "path": this.path,
          "branchDev": this.branch
      }
    ];
  }
```

tentativa no express

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));


app.post('/checkout', cors(),function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.path);
)};
```

console

```
user@bitter:/var/www/html/gitrun$ node express.js 
[ { path: '/var/www/html/gitrun', branchDev: ' git-1' } ]
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está enviando um array para o node.js. Altera o código do Angular apra enviar sem ser array.

```
this.appService.getcheckout(this.post()).subscribe(checkout => {
      this.log = this.log+ checkout
    });
post(){
    return 
      {
          "path": this.path,
          "branchDev": this.branch
      };
  }
```

Você poderia ler assim:

```
console.log(req.body[0].path);
```